# How do I write code with comments in it?

Tags: feature-request, comments, code-formatting

I wanted to edit [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312260/javafx-application-hide-osx-dock-icon/32984600#32984600), because there is a code comment (that starts with `/**` and ends with `*/`) in the code, and that's why code wasn't shown properly.

But selecting the whole code and marking it as a code block or pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> button doesn't work.

How do I insert a code with comments in the answer?

And the code should be marked up in the language it was written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to the language tag is to add another level of indentation (which I do quickly with Notepad++ or whatever code editor of your choice).

So effectively, what's in the answer currently...

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->

    /**
     - This class is intended to start application as AWT application before initializing
     - JavaFX application. JavaFX does not support dock-icon-less application so we are 
     - creating JavaFX application from AWT application so that we can achieve the desired
     - functionality.
     - */

    public class AWTMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // This is awt property which enables dock-icon-less
            // applications 
            System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true");
            java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

            // This is a call to JavaFX application main method.
            // From now on we are transferring control to FX application. 
            FXMain.main(args);
        }
    }
```

...can be duplicated without the `<!-- language: lang-java -->` line as follows:

```
        /**
         - This class is intended to start application as AWT application before initializing
         - JavaFX application. JavaFX does not support dock-icon-less application so we are 
         - creating JavaFX application from AWT application so that we can achieve the desired
         - functionality.
         - */

        public class AWTMain {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                // This is awt property which enables dock-icon-less
                // applications 
                System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true");
                java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

                // This is a call to JavaFX application main method.
                // From now on we are transferring control to FX application. 
                FXMain.main(args);
            }
        }
```

As an additional bonus, the additional indentation will also nest your code within the bulleted list item in case that was important to you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Pre tags, vaguely like so would work. (I've got the enclosing tags in backticks so you can see what I did)

`<pre>`

```
/**
tags should do the trick
*/
```

`</pre>`

I've done the edits on the linked answer, hopefully appropriately.

Comment: I know it can be done by pre tag. There is another question will stackoverlow format/style it as a code?

Comment: on SO, apparently tags on the main question would do that. There's also some markup for language tags I'm embarrassed to say I completely forgot about. For your *specific* case though, pre tags are the *right* way, and not mentioned in the question.

Comment: After approval I see that it doesn't markup. How about adding tag in the answer like `[tag:java]`?

Comment: No, it doesn't either. So the only solution is pre tag it seems.